# How to add custom field to certificate using openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509

I'm trying to create certificates for internal use. I'm the CA and I would like to have an additional field in my client certificates so that when I generate a certificate for a client, it will hold some specific data in that field.

I read the following [article](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/apps/x509v3_config.html) and [another article](http://the.randomengineer.com/2014/04/18/adding-custom-data-to-x-509-ssl-certificates/) and I understand that I can do that with x509 v3 format by generating an oid for each field, and then use it with the `-extfile` parameter when creating the public key
so I took the deafult /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf config file and uncomment one of the mentioned fields:

```
[ new_oids ]
testoid1 = 1.2.3.4
```

Then I generate all the certificates by the following:

```
openssl genrsa -aes256 -out ca-key.pem 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 365 -key ca-key.pem -sha256 -out ca.pem -config openssl.cnf 
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 4096
openssl req -subj '/CN=client' -new -key key.pem -out client.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -sha256 -in client.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem  -CAcreateserial -out cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
```

Where extfile.cnf content is:

```
1.2.3.4 = Something
```

I get:

```
Error Loading extension section default
140218200073872:error:22097082:X509 V3 routines:DO_EXT_NCONF:unknown extension name:v3_conf.c:125:
140218200073872:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:v3_conf.c:95:name=1.2.3.4, value=Something
unable to write 'random state'
```

Documentation in this topic is lacking. Can someone walk me through it and explain how it can be done?

Comment: A nice blog detailing basics of adding extension fields in x509 certificate [here](https://lalmohan.co.nz/2020/02/10/create-and-install-a-san-certificate-subject-alternative-name-in-windows-without-third-party-tools/).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In order to add a custom field, first create a config file:

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req

[v3_req]
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8=ASN1:UTF8String:Something
```

Then, create the CSR:

```
openssl req [params] -out mycsr.csr -config myconfig.cnf
```

Then, Create the certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -in mycsr.csr [params] -out mycert.pem -extfile myconfig.cnf -extensions v3_req
```

Comment: I am having the same problem, and I tried with what is suggested here but I'm getting this error: unable to find 'distinguished_name' in config. Does my config file has to have only what is written above or something else?

Comment: @Sandra better late than never: https://superuser.com/questions/947061/openssl-unable-to-find-distinguished-name-in-config/1118045 (Essentially, find the two above sections in your already existing `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf` and add the two lines if they're missing)

Comment: How can you do the same for request attributes instead of request extensions? The type definition of the value doesn't work - it always uses UTF8String